# Is there any procedure to distinguish the user by organization wise using Google analytics + firebase + tag manager in Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

Need to distinguish the user according to organization-wise check-in check-out by using Google analytics + firebase + tag manager in Android app.
Could you suggest the procedure to implement above requirement.